# Rails: Session data stored in a request doesn't persist in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, server, vite

I want to use a Ruby on Rails API to handle login/sign in from users on a Vite + React front end app.

I want to store a `user_id` on the session so that when the user logs in once and come back to the page they are automatically sent to the user page and don't have to log in again, but when I go to check the session[:user_id] on a request it is empty.

The functions that handle the session:

```
def create
        @user = User.new(name: params[:user][:name], email: params[:user][:email], password: params[:user][:password])
        if @user.save
            session[:user] = @user.id
            puts session[:user]
            render json: {error: false, message: 'User Created', user: @user}, status: 200
        else
            render error: {error: 'Unable to create User' }, status: 400
        end
    end

def login
        @user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email], password: params[:user][:password])
        if @user.present?
            session[:user] = @user.id
            puts session[:user]
            render json: {error: false, message: 'User Exists', user: @user}, status: 200
        else
            render json: {error: true, message: 'User not found'}, status: 400
        end
    end
```

The `puts session[:user]` returns the id that is given to the user on the database.

When on my front end after the user is created or logs in, they are redirected to the home page, where I do a request to check if there is an active session, and if there is, they are then redirected to the user page.

The function to check the session:

```
def checkSession
        puts session[:user]
        if session[:user]
            @user = User.find_by(id: session[:user])
            render json: {error: false, message: 'User in session', user: @user}, status: 200
        else
            render json: {error: true, message: 'No active session'}, status: 400
        end
    end
```

The `puts session[:user]` returns empty, and my front end receives que message of "No active session"

I have my session configuration like this on `config/application.rb`

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session'
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.middleware.use config.session_store, config.session_options
```

Both my API and Front End are running locally on different ports

Software versions:
`Ruby 3.2.2`
`Rails 7.0.7`

I have seen some solutions to this problem, but so far I haven't been able to solve it, If anyone has any idea what is wrong or what I could do to solve this it would be appreciated

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters exclusively. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: Make sure whatever client you're using to access this sends in all the cookies it's given or your session might reset. Check in the Network inspector of your browser to see what's being sent. `session.id` will also cycle when a new session is created.

Comment: Suspect your browser is not sending the cookie header, probably because Vite has it on a different domain or something. You can confirm by logging what your browser is sending (in your controller action): `logger.debug request.env["HTTP_COOKIE"]` No idea about Vite, sorry, but hopefully this is a step closer to solving the underlying issue. Note I also added the Vite tag to your question. Also btw, you don't need the second two lines in your config, that middleware is already loaded by Rails.

Comment: What are you going on about capitals @tadman?

Comment: @smathy There's a very strong convention in Ruby to use lower-case *only* for variables and method names, as in `check_session` here.

Comment: Right, but your comment was about leading capitals being for constants, anyway maybe it was just me who wasn't picking up that you were talking about the snake vs camel case for the `checkSession` method.